# RedHat Server 7.3 trying to mount nfs share using NFS4

Tags: linux, redhat, nfs, mount, nfs4

I am trying to mount a share located on Server1 using NFSv4, instead of NFSv3. The host server is running RHEL 5.1 (don't ask), and the client is running RHEL 7.3. I am able to mount it using NFSv3 without problems, but I am doing a ton of file moving daily with small files, and I think performance would improve significantly if I used NFSv4.

I am running the following command:

```
mount -v -type nfs4 server1:/export/foo /nfsmnt/foo
```

And I get:

```
mount(2): Input/output error
mount system call failed
```

If I do

```
mount -v -type nfs -o nfsvers=3 server1:/export/foo /nfsmnt/foo
```

It works just fine.

I have confirmed that NFSv4 is supported on both client and server, using rpcinfo -p. The firewall is currently turned off on both.

Comment: If I remember well, Redhat 5 uses nfs 3 by default.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right, but I am requesting NFS4 in the mount command, and the 5.1 server does support version 4, and rpcinfo -p confirms that.

Comment: can you show your /etc/exportfs from the nfs server?

Answer (score 2):

When you have an older NFS server, it sometimes helps to use `nolock` on a mount:

```
mount -v -type nfs4 -o nolock server1:/export/foo /nfsmnt/foo
```

Comment: I tried this by itself, and also in conjunction with @Godvil's comment. Neither method worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try using mount like this for more compability:

```
mount -v -type nfs -o vers=4,proto=tcp server1:/export/foo /nfsmnt/foo
```

Comment: I tried this by itself, and also in conjunction with @kristtian's comment. Neither method worked.

Comment: Please try `mount` with `-vvv` argument for full verbosity and post the output here. You could also check your `/var/log/messages` log for more infos!